# How to denote the graph of a function $f$ over an interval $[a;b]$?

Tags: functions, notation, graphing-functions

Is there a conventional notation to write it? I am thinking in writing it as $f_{[a;b]}$.

Comment: What is your notation for the graph of a function on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Just $f$ without the subscript.

Comment: I've seen $(x, f(x))$. That is, it's the set of all ordered pairs.

Answer (score 1):

For $f : A \to B$:
$$
G_f = \{ (x, f(x)) \in A \times B \mid x \in A \}
$$
I am not sure if there is a different notation for some interval $A = [a, b]$.

Comment: I wouldn't call that notation conventional, though it works.  Indeed, for $f: A\to B$, it is common to write $f[A]$ to express $\{f(a)\mid a \in A\}$, where $A = [a, b]\subset \mathbb R$

Comment: @amWhy I would say that it depends a lot on context.  I've seen the notation $\Gamma(f) := \{ (x,f(x)) : x \in \operatorname{Dom}(f) \}$, from which the notation $\Gamma(f|_{[a,b]})$ might be reasonable (where $f|_{[a,b]}$ is a moderately common notation for the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[a,b]$).  Something similar could be done with the notation that mvw suggests:  $G_{f|_{[a,b]}}$, though the subscripts are a little awkward there.

Comment: Might be an Anglo / European difference. Just comparing the English language Wikipedia article vs the French/Dutch/German/Italian.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit construction of a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is  a *functional relation* from $A$ to $B$. So $f \subset A \times B$. A pair $(a,b) \in f$ defines the notation $f(a)=b$.

If by *graph* of $f$ you mean the set of all points $(x,f(x))$ in the "plane", then the graph is precisely $f$.

If you need to restrict the *domain* of the function, then your $f_{[a;b]}$ notation does the job, although it may not be conventional.